# Help Multiple controls with the same ID '' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs

Tags: asp.net

i keep getting this and nothin is helpful can some one solve this error i am addinfg images at runtime and links are fetched from db and dynamic image control are made but this error is getting in my way.
Multiple controls with the same ID 'projectimg8' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.

```
   string get = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text;
    DataSet ds = con.getprojectgallery(get);
    if (ds!=null)
    {
        int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Image img = new Image();
            img.ID = "projectimg" + count.ToString();
            img.ImageUrl = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
            img.Height = 80;
            img.Width = 80;
            img.ToolTip = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
            pnlgallery.Controls.Add(img);
            pnlgallery.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
        }
```

Comment: Error message is pretty clear about cause of error: there is controls with same id. So, make that there would be no controls with same id.

Comment: projectimg+i.tostring() is a unique name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to:

```
img.ID = "projectimg" + i.ToString();
```

You need the incremented count, not the count variable itself.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you generate your images they all have unique IDs.

It would be easier of you showed us some code..

**Edit:**

Thanks for the code.

In the line where you set ID you use same number every time because `count` represents the number of rows.

You could use Matt's code, or:

```
img.ID = String.Format("projectimg{0}", i);
```

Comment: string get = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text;
        DataSet ds = con.getprojectgallery(get);
        if (ds!=null)
        {
            int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                Image img = new Image();
                img.ID = "projectimg" + count.ToString();
                img.ImageUrl = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
                img.Height = 80;
                img.Width = 80;
                img.ToolTip = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
                pnlgallery.Controls.Add(img);
}

Comment: Check my updated post. Also, make sure next time you edit your question and include source there - it looks much better formatted ;)